# cURL error 35 SSL Connect Error on hostgator live server

Tags: php, curl, https

I have searched a lot for this issue on the internet even on stackoverflow but unable to reach at certain solution. I'm using the following code to make a curl request to one of https website.

```
<?php 

/**
 * Get a web file (HTML, XHTML, XML, image, etc.) from a URL.  Return an
 * array containing the HTTP server response header fields and content.
 */
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_web_page('https://savedeo.com/download?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DbVl3om0-GFE'));die;

?>
```

This code is absolutely working fine at my localhost xampp but not working on hostgator shared hosting. Can anybody tell me the exact issue or what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: `echo phpinfo();` and be sure that `curl` is installed and working on shared hosting

Comment: Yes it enabled and working fine for http sites

Comment: please post your `curl error`

Answer (score 0):

Add 'CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true' to your options array to give a more detailed output this should give you the cause.

If you have access to the firewall settings ensure the port for the connection is actually open.